# UIActivityItemSource render image in background

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, grand-central-dispatch

My app takes about 10 seconds to render a full-resolution image with many filters applied. I want to allow the user to save it or share it using `UIActivityViewController`. I've subclassed `UIActivityItemSource` so it provides a thumbnail when the activity view opens.

How can I make it so my item source renders the image in the background? Specifically, I would like to allow the view controller to minimize and display a progress bar.

I already have the progress bar working, I just need to know how to do the following in the background:

```
func activityViewController(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: String) -> AnyObject? {

    // this step takes 10 seconds
    // is there any way to do it in the background?
    // So: the activity view can minimize
    // and the main thread is free to update my progress bar

    let image = renderFullImage()

    return image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to use a `UIActivityItemProvider` instead of `UIActivityItemSource`. You are supposed to override the `item` method, which is already called in the background.